# Swift - Error calling a function from another function

Tags: ios, swift

While following Apple's book ["The Swift Programming Language"](https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l)

I ran across an issue while working on the "EXPERIMENT - Write a function that calculates the average of its arguments." from the first chapter.

To determine the average of a set of numbers, I want to reuse my sum of numbers [setOf(numbers: Int...)] function and divide by the count of numbers [numbers.count].  I am receiving the Error:

```
Could not find an overload for '__conversions' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

when I try to call `sumOf(numbers)` from my `averageOf(numbers)` function.

What should I change to call my `sumOf(numbers)` function correctly, from my `averageOf(numbers)` function?

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0 //0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum  //651
}
sumOf(42, 597, 12)  //651

func averageOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = sumOf(numbers) //Issue in this line
    return  sum / numbers.count
}
averageOf(42, 597, 12)
```

*Paste the code above into a new Xcode 6 playground to recreate.*

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S11zh.png) (I need 10 reputation points before I can post the image.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24024376/1639670

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a different type as the function expects. Apparently `Int...` is not the same as `Int[]`.

You could create an override that accepts `Int[]` and returns the sum.