# Swift function with args... pass to another function with args

Tags: swift, arguments, args

I have a simple problem. I tried search in many blogs about this question but all site return how function in swift work, but I need this case.

My custom function is:

```
func getLocalizeWithParams(args:CVarArgType...)->String {
     return NSString.localizedStringWithFormat(self, args); //error: Expected expression in list of expressions
}
```

How I do to pass my args to other system function with args?

Thanks advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing an array to a function with variable number of args in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024376/passing-an-array-to-a-function-with-variable-number-of-args-in-swift)

Comment: I saw this post, but it didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: How about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110853/passing-in-variable-number-of-args-from-one-function-to-another-in-swift It's exactly the same as your problem. It was marked as a duplicate of the above one; that's why I used that one.

Comment: The issue is same, but he has two functions constructed by self and he can modify to receive array and fix, in my issue I have one owner function and need use a system function.. It is different. My luck is someone help me with a good solution and work fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Similar as in (Objective-)C, you cannot pass a variable argument list
directly to another function. You have to create a `CVaListPointer`
(the Swift equivalent of `va_list` in C) and call a function which 
takes a `CVaListPointer` parameter.

So this could be what you are looking for:

```
extension String {
    func getLocalizeWithParams(args : CVarArgType...) -> String {
        return withVaList(args) {
            NSString(format: self, locale: NSLocale.currentLocale(), arguments: $0)
        } as String
    }
}
```

`withVaList()` creates a `CVaListPointer` from the given argument list
and calls the closure with this pointer as argument.

Example (from the `NSString` documentation):

```
let msg = "%@:  %f\n".getLocalizeWithParams("Cost", 1234.56)
print(msg)
```

Output for US locale:

```
Cost:  1,234.560000
```

Output for German locale:

```
Cost:  1.234,560000
```

---

**Update:** As of **Swift 3/4/5** one can pass the arguments to

```
String(format: String, locale: Locale?, arguments: [CVarArg])
```

directly:

```
extension String {
    func getLocalizeWithParams(_ args : CVarArg...) -> String {
        return String(format: self, locale: .current, arguments: args)
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not correctly transform localized string.

Comment: Some explaining comment for the downvote would be extremely helpful. If anything is wrong here, let me know so that I can try to fix it.

Comment: @BorutTomazin: I have added an example (which is the example from the NSString documentation for localizedStringWithFormat. Please let me know what is wrong here. Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: It works for translation, but does not work for plurals. I've modified your method a bit to make this work for plurals also. Thanks!

Comment: this is crashing on swift 4.0.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you're using `NSString.localizedStringWithFormat(self, args)` incorrectly. Otherwise nothing wrong with using args to call another function.

If you look below, you need to specify the format as NSString as the first argument:
`NSString.localizedStringWithFormat(format: NSString, args: CVarArgType...)`

This SO question explains how to use it in Swift: [iOS Swift and localizedStringWithFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862960/ios-swift-and-localizedstringwithformat)

Comment: Thank you, but I know how work localizedStringWithFormat, I need know how pass args... params to another function like localizedStringWithFormat  args... understand? Sry my english

Comment: When you pass args to getLocalizeWithParams( ), you can use that for any function call within that function. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Args... in **getLocalizeWithParams()** is an _Array_, my array can contain **n** items, because this i need pass to **NSString.localizedStringWithFormat** a **n** values, and when i try this way I do, it pass one array not a many values to **NSString.localizedStringWithFormat**