# Swift Issue in passing variable number of parameters

Tags: swift, arguments

I have the following code:

```
public static func e(file: String = __FILE__,
    function: String = __FUNCTION__,
    line: Int = __LINE__,format: String, args: CVarArgType...)
{
    NSLog([%d]\t [%@] " + format,line,function, args); //<<< I have no idea how to pass the params here
}
```

I get compiler error on NSLog that can not be called as I did.

Simply I need to print the var args, function name and line using a single NSLOG call.

Answer (score 4):

Similar as in [Swift function with args... pass to another function with args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399882/swift-function-with-args-pass-to-another-function-with-args),
you have to create a `CVaListPointer` (the Swift equivalent of `va_list` in C) and call a function which takes a `CVaListPointer` parameter,
in this case `NSLogv()`.

```
public class Logger {
    public static func e(
        format: String,
        file: String = __FILE__,
        function: String = __FUNCTION__,
        line: Int = __LINE__,
        args: CVarArgType...)
    {
        let extendedFormat = "[%d]\t [%@] " + format
        let extendedArgs : [CVarArgType] = [ line, function ] + args
        withVaList(extendedArgs) { NSLogv(extendedFormat, $0) }
    }
}

// Example usage:
Logger.e("x = %d, y = %f, z = %@", args: 13, 1.23, "foo")
```

I have made `format` the first parameter, so that is has no external
parameter name. The variable argument list must be the last parameter
in **Swift 1.2**, and the external parameter cannot be avoided in this
combination with default parameters.

In **Swift 2** you can avoid the external parameter name for the
variable arguments:

```
public class Logger {
    public static func e(
        format: String,
        _ args: CVarArgType...,
        file: String = __FILE__,
        function: String = __FUNCTION__,
        line: Int = __LINE__)
    {
        let extendedFormat = "[%d]\t [%@] " + format
        let extendedArgs : [CVarArgType] = [ line, function ] + args
        withVaList(extendedArgs) { NSLogv(extendedFormat, $0) }
    }
}

// Example usage:
Logger.e("x = %d, y = %f, z = %@", 13, 1.23, "foo")
```

Comment: Current (Xcode 7.3) syntax is `#file`, `#function`, `#line` (and thanks)