# Swift protocol extension: fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes

Tags: swift2, protocol-extension

I've defined a protocol with a protocol extension to simplify working with `NSError`.

```
protocol NSErrorConvertible: RawRepresentable {
    var domain: String { get }
    var localizedDescription: String { get }
}

extension NSErrorConvertible where RawValue == Int {
    func generateError(parameters parameters: [String] = []) -> NSError {
        let error = self.generateError(format: self.localizedDescription, parameters: parameters)
        return error
    }

    func generateError(format format: String, parameters: [String] = []) -> NSError {
        let description = String(format: format, arguments: parameters) // <-- BREAK
        let error = NSError(domain: self.domain, code: self.rawValue, localizedDescription: description)
        return error
    }
}

extension NSError {
    convenience init(domain: String, code: Int, localizedDescription: String) {
        let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : localizedDescription]
        self.init(domain: domain, code: code, userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}
```

Here's how the protocol is used:

```
enum DefaultEngineErrors: Int, NSErrorConvertible {
    case ImagesNotSupported
    case FooDoesNotHaveABar
    case NilBar

    var domain: String { return "DefaultEngineErrors" }

    var localizedDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .ImagesNotSupported: return "%s: Images are not supported."
        case .FooDoesNotHaveABar: return "%s: Foo does not have a bar."
        case .NilBar:             return "%s: The bar is nil."
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how the protocol extension methods are called:

```
let error = DefaultEngineErrors.FooDoesNotHaveABar.generateError(parameters: ["\(foo.id)"])
```

When this code is run, the debugger breaks on the line that builds the description in the second `generateError` extension function and the following message is displayed in the debugger console:

**fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes**

Note that if I replace the call to `String(format:)` with just `format`, everything works fine.

Q: What is wrong with what I've done here?

In addition to this, I can't examine the parameters in the protocol extension.  The following message is displayed when I try:

```
(lldb) po format
error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: non-nominal type '$__lldb_context' (aka 'Self') cannot be extended
extension $__lldb_context {                            
^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<EXPR>:15:5: error: value of type 'DefaultEngineErrors' has no member '$__lldb_wrapped_expr_54'
    $__lldb_injected_self.$__lldb_wrapped_expr_54(     
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Swift string Array is not compatible with CVarArgType... or [CVarArgType]`

try using.

```
extension NSErrorConvertible where RawValue == Int {
    func generateError(format format: String) -> NSError {
        let error = NSError(domain: self.domain, code: self.rawValue, localizedDescription: format)
        return error
    }
    func generateError(args : CVarArgType...) -> NSError {
        let returnString = NSString(format: self.localizedDescription, arguments: getVaList(args)) as String
//        let returnString = withVaList(args) {
//            NSString(format: self.localizedDescription, arguments: $0)
//        } as String
        let error = generateError(format: returnString)
        return error
    }
}

enum DefaultEngineErrors: Int, NSErrorConvertible {
    case ImagesNotSupported
    case FooDoesNotHaveABar
    case FooWithMultiPar
    case NilBar

    var domain: String { return "DefaultEngineErrors" }

    var localizedDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .ImagesNotSupported: return "%@: Images are not supported."
        case .FooDoesNotHaveABar: return "%@: Foo does not have a bar."
        case .FooWithMultiPar: return "%@:%@ Foo does not have a bar."
        case .NilBar:             return "%@: The bar is nil."
        }
    }
}

print(DefaultEngineErrors.FooDoesNotHaveABar.generateError("test"))
print(DefaultEngineErrors.FooWithMultiPar.generateError("test1","test2"))
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29401619/1721884)

Comment: That was it.  Thanks Rahul.