# Localizing a string

Tags: ios, string, swift, localization

So I'm localizing a project using an Extension to NSString that I found on SO. That extension looks like this:

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

I however have come across strings in my Localizable.strings list that contain parameters. For example:

```
"explore_item_desc1" = "Welcome to rent my %1$s!";
```

Before I was able to do this:

```
uiLabel.text = "localizedString".localized
```

How do I do something similar for those strings holding parameters?

Comment: maybe you can do something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26277912/1219956) (make your `localized` var into a func with variable parameters instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your localized keys should look like this:

```
"localized_key_name1" = "foo";

"localized_key_name2" = "%@ foo %@";
```

Make your `localized` variable into a function rather

```
extension String {
     var localized: String {
         return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
     }
     func localized(args : CVarArgType...) -> String {
         return withVaList(args, { (f:CVaListPointer) -> String in
        (NSString.init(format:NSLocalizedString(self, comment:""), arguments: f) as String)
     })
  }
}
```

usage without Parameters

```
uiLabel.text = "localized_key_name1".localized   // "foo"
```

usage with Parameters

```
uiLabel.text = "localized_key_name2".localized("param1", "param2")   // "param1 foo param2"
```

[credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29401619/1219956)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is almost working. When I use it it prints the params strangely though. So using: print("explore_item_desc1".localized("param1")) will result in: Welcome to rent my ¯Ûò!

Comment: ah hmm, strange, let me fiddle around a bit with it

Comment: it seems swift has a problem with passing variadic arguments to other functions that have variadic arguments, after googling around it seems swift just doesnt support it properly yet

Comment: I only need to pass in 1 parameter though, after changing (params: String...) to (param: String) it is still printing out the same line.

Comment: it seems the problem has already been solved http://stackoverflow.com/a/29401619/1219956

Comment: Even with that post I'm not able to get it work, anyway you can add the right function to the snippet proposed by you above?

Comment: hmm ye it doesnt seem to work for me either, seems swift just doesnt want you to pass variadic parameters at all heh, ill let you know if i find a proper solution, but its looking dire at the moment :(

Comment: ok got it to work, if you use the NSString type of formatting, it seems to work, so use `%@` with my updated solution

Comment: Still not exactly what I'm looking for. This: print("explore_item_desc1 %@".localizedParam(name)) will print out: "explore_item_desc1 梯"  when I'm hoping to get "Welcome to rent my 梯!" it's not localizing explore_item_desc1 from my Strings file this way.

Comment: oh no, you still should use your key how it is (so just "explore_item_desc1") in the values of the localized strings you must use the %@ (i was just using the key as the same as the value in my case) so `"explore_item_desc1" = "Welcome to rent my %@";`

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!

Comment: good edit having both the var and the function, but you can name the func and the var the same then you can use `.localized("param")` or `.localized` (more elegant in my opinion), but up to you