# Swift Variable Argument

Tags: ios, swift

In "The Swift Programming Language", Functions and Closures, there is a sample code to calculate the total as below:

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}
```

As part of the following experiment, I tried the following function to calculate the average

```
 func averageOf(numbers : Int...) -> Int {
        var argument:Array = numbers
        var average = sumOf(argument) / numbers.count
        return average
    }
```

However, I get the following error

> [Int] is not convertible to Int

I have also tried the following line with no success
        var average = sumOf(numbers) / numbers.count

Any idea whats going on underneath? Why is sumOf parameter is treating it as Int instead of an array when the book clearly states that

> “Functions can also take a variable number of arguments, collecting
>   them into an array.”

Comment: See this for answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024376/passing-an-array-to-a-function-with-variable-number-of-args-in-swift

Comment: Hi Mike, I think the duplicate marked by dpassage is more relevant than yours.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you function is ok if you try to call it properly.

```
sumOf(25,23,43,23)
```

But if you would like to call array use this code :

```
import UIKit

var someInts = [Int]()
someInts.append(8)
someInts.append(6)
someInts.append(6)
someInts.append(3)
someInts.append(5)

func sumOf(numbers: [Int]) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}


sumOf(someInts)
```

The main problem that in function you declare parameter not as array but like undefined amount of the integers

Comment: Yeah, but sumOf([25,23,43,23]) won't work, because sumOf expects a variable number of ints as arguments, not an array of Int. Swift has no automatic conversion for that. Why not defining a second sumOf like func sumOf(numbers: Int[]) -> Int

Comment: Look correctly sumOf(25,23,43,23) without []. It will work my friend

Comment: So why you put -1 because you do not read my answer ?

Comment: Sorry, wrong click :-) And you seem to have answered your question by yourself in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

Just change definition of method To

```
func sumOf(numbers: [Int]) -> Int
```

Instead Of

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int
```

Because you are passing array as an argument to **func sumOf** function, which is not expected as its define.