# What's the difference between `Int...` and `[Int]` in Swift?

Tags: swift

```
// first segment
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: Int -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func lessThanTen(number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < 10
}
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
hasAnyMatches(numbers, condition: lessThanTen)

// second segment
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}
sumOf()
sumOf(42, 597, 12)
```

What's the difference between `list` in segment 1 and `numbers` in segment 2? Why one is `[Int]` another is `Int...`?

I try to exchange them in playground, error was shown.

Comment: You never feed an array to `sumOf`; at most three *separate* integers. `hasAnyMatches`, however, takes `numbers` as its first argument, which is an array.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024376/passing-an-array-to-a-function-with-variable-number-of-args-in-swift

Comment: `[Int]` is int array, `Int...` is more int parameter.

Comment: @LeoDabus oh! Those are copy from The Swift Programming Language(Swift 2 Prerelease)...

Comment: @30000ft    `Int...` it is called a Variadic Parameter, which means the number of parameters is not fixed.  Only inside the function your variadic parameter is accessible as an array of Int. `[Int]` Is an array of Integers and you can pass it as a single parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Int]

This indicates the parameter is a array type.

### Int...

This indicates the parameter is a variadic parameter.
A variadic parameter accepts zero or more values of a specified type.

### Difference

A variadic parameter is used as a constant array within function body, the difference happens in calling function, we can call function with variadic parameter in none parameter style, like function_variadic_type(), and function with array type can't do this, there must be a array passed into function, like function_array_type([1, 2]).

Answer (score 0):

It has no difference. Your code is fine. You just have to delete 'condition' in line 17.
The code should be like this

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: Int -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func lessThanTen(number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < 10
}
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
hasAnyMatches(numbers, lessThanTen)

// second segment
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}
sumOf()
sumOf(42, 597, 12)
```