# swift something wrong with String init(format... method?

Tags: string, swift

```
let elem1 = "1"
let elem2 = "2"
let array = [elem1, elem2]
let format = "%@ != %@"

//compiler error
//can't find an initializer for type...
let str = String(format: format, arguments: elem1, elem2)

//no errors but wrong output
//("%@ != %@", "1", "2")
let str = String(format: format, _arguments: elem1, elem2)

//runtime error
//fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes
//this is what I need
let str = String(format: format, arguments: array)

//only this works with the right output
//1 != 2
let str = String(format: format, arguments: [elem1, elem2])

print(str)
```

tested in xcode7 beta and xcode6.3, I couldn't find a workaround right now

Comment: Have you tried using NSString instead of String?

Comment: @LeoDabus is right and the reason why `String(format: format, arguments: array)` doesn't work is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024376/passing-an-array-to-a-function-with-variable-number-of-args-in-swift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this syntax (XCode 7):

```
import Foundation

let elem1 = "1"
let elem2 = "2"
let format = "%@ != %@"
let str = String(format: format, elem1, elem2) // "1 !=2"
print(str) // "1 != 2\n"
```

The trick is to specify the overloaded ctor with format: and skip arguments: all together.