# Why can't I pass an array to a vararg in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, variadic-functions

I have this function:

```
func doStuff(stuff: Int...) {
    print(stuff)
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
doStuff(array)
```

And it does not compile!

I mean, this makes no sense, right? The function is supposed to accept a list of things, and I am giving it a list of things. How come this doesn't work?

Here's some background info (you can skip it)

---

I have this `NSManagedObject` subclass:

```
class Entry: NSManagedObject {

    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        // irrelevent
    }

    convenience init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext, title: String, content: String, date: NSDate) {
        // irrelevent
    }
}

extension Entry {

    @NSManaged var content: String?
    @NSManaged var date: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var title: String?

}
```

In one of my view controllers, I fetch all the `Entry`s in `viewDidLoad` and I stored the fetched stuff in a variable called `anyObjs` which is of type `[AnyObject]`

I want to turn this `[AnyObject]` to a `[NSDate: Entry]`, where the keys are the values' `date` property. I want it this way in order to easily access an `Entry` using an `NSDate`.

So I tried the following:

```
let literal = anyObjs!.map { (($0 as! Entry).date!, $0 as! Entry) }
entries = [NSDate: Entry](dictionaryLiteral: literal)
```

And I found out that I can't pass a `[(NSDate, Entry)]` to `(NSDate, Entry)...`!

---

"That's easy" you might say, "just pass all the elements in the array as varargs using the subscript!"

```
doStuff(array[0], array[1], array[2])
```

But this doesn't work if I don't know how many items there are.

Another workaround that doesn't work is to create a function that accepts an array:

```
func doStuff(array: [Int]) {
    print(array)
}
```

This doesn't work either because if I don't know the exact implementation of the function, I cannot rewrite it in the new function.

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an array to a function with variable number of args in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024376/passing-an-array-to-a-function-with-variable-number-of-args-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right! There ought to be a method for getting a dictionary from an array of tuples.

```
extension Dictionary {
    init(tuples: [Element]) {
        self.init()

        for (key, value) in tuples {
            self.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

OK, now that's done, let's see.

```
let tuples = anyObjs!.map { (($0 as! Entry).date!, $0 as! Entry) }
let entries = [NSDate: Entry](tuples: tuples)
```

Or combine the two lines

```
let entries = [NSDate: Entry](tuples: anyObjs!.map { (($0 as! Entry).date!, $0 as! Entry) })
```

Comment: But what if I don't know the exact implementation of a method? Then I can't rewrite it as a method that takes an array. Or can I?

Comment: @Sweeper You could suggest Variadic Parameters splatting to [swift-evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/), but considering they have approved [Remove implicit tuple splat behavior from function applications](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0029-remove-implicit-tuple-splat.md), I think they will reject the proposal.