# port Objective-C macro using varargs to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert this macro:

```
#define returnAsync(block, ...) if (block) { dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ block(__VA_ARGS__); }); } return;
```

I've ended up at this:

```
func returnAsync(block: (Any?...) -> (), args: Any?...) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        block(args)
    }
    return
}
```

but when I try to call that function like so:

```
let block: (Int, Int) -> () = { first, second in print(first + second) }
returnAsync(block, 2, 5)
```

I get errors complaining about parameter types which makes sense consider `Any?...` really means a function takes an array of arguments of type `[Any?]` of variable length.

Is there any way to port the macro to Swift or am I out of luck?

Comment: Related: [Passing an array to a function with variable number of args in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24024376)

Comment: Also relevant: [The missing `apply` function in Swift](https://www.drivenbycode.com/the-missing-apply-function-in-swift/)

Comment: That's an example where someone tried to be clever with macros. Just do it without macros.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm asking what that method signature would look like.