# How to pass parameter of AnyObject... to function which parameter need AnyObject

Tags: swift, arguments, nsattributedstring

I'am using function of

```
NSAttributedString(attributes: [String : AnyObject]?, format: String, arguments: AnyObject...)
```

And I want to customize an general function to call this function above. So I need to send parameter

> arguments: AnyObject...

But this parameter will become [AnyObject] in my customize function. How to fix it?

**Update**:

When I use code bellow:

```
typealias Function = ([String : AnyObject]?, String, [AnyObject]) -> NSAttributedString
let myAttributedString = unsafeBitCast(NSAttributedString(attributes:format:_:) , Function.self)
```

It will give error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'NSAttributedString(attributes:format:_:)'

**Update:(Temp Solution)**

I get an temp solution which is ugly but works just enough for me.

```
// NOTE: here arguments may be String or NSAttributedString
private func getAttributedString(withFormat format: String, _ arguments: AnyObject..., withUnderLine: Bool = false) -> NSAttributedString {
    var attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: #someFont,
                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName: #someColor]
     if withUnderLine {
          attributes[NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName] = NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue
     }

     switch arguments.count {
         case 0:
             return NSAttributedString(attributes: attributes, format: format)
         case 1:
             return NSAttributedString(attributes: attributes, format: format, arguments[0])
         case 2:
             return NSAttributedString(attributes: attributes, format: format, arguments[0], arguments[1])
         case 3:
             return NSAttributedString(attributes: attributes, format: format, arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2])
         case 4:
             return NSAttributedString(attributes: attributes, format: format, arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3])
         default:
             assert(arguments.count <= 4)
             return NSAttributedString(attributes: attributes, format: format, arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3])
         }  
     }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an array to a function with variable number of args in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024376/passing-an-array-to-a-function-with-variable-number-of-args-in-swift)

Comment: I know how to do it with Int, but don't know how to do this with AnyObject

Comment: Oh, is the status of https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-128 not up to date? How do you do it with Int?

Comment: The answer from CC-Dog: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27731101/1530581

Comment: Thank you. How come you don't use that solution or post the error you get when trying?

Comment: First problem is my Xcode can't found this NSAttributedString(attributes: [String : AnyObject]?, format: String, arguments: AnyObject..)  init function in my Playground. And I can't fund it in swift document. I have logged in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845138/i-can-wire-function-with-code-completion-but-cant-found-it-in-header-file-for

Comment: Second problem is when I try with typealias Function2 = ([AnyObject]) -> AnyObject, I will get error: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list

Comment: When I use unsafeBitCast(NSAttributedString(attributes:format:_:) , Function.self), it will give error of error: use of unresolved identifier 'nsattributedstring(attributes:formatter:_:)'

Comment: @Andreas  I found an temp ugly solution for my problem.

Comment: Interesting, but I could not find that init in the docs. Also the function signatures you've posted don't look the same.

Comment: @Andreas I also could not found this init in docs, but this can be auto complete by my XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referencing the initializer, you should use `NSAttributedString.init(attributes:format:_:)`

The full call becomes `unsafeBitCast(NSAttributedString.init(attributes:format:_:), to: Function.self)`

I've just tried something similar in Swift Playgrounds on iPad:

[image: Playgrounds screenshot]

Comment: Aha, Excellent!

Comment: Where you found this? I didn't found anything about in document, maybe I searched without correct keys. Thanks.

Comment: I vaguely remember there are some examples like `[1, 2, 3].map(String.init)` which shows that initializer can be referenced in this way.