# Assign list of variadic parameters to variable

Tags: ios, swift

This is the case:

```
public enum NodeFeature: UInt16 {
    case relay      = 0x01
    case proxy      = 0x02
    case friend     = 0x04
    case lpn        = 0x08
}

public struct NodeFeatures {
    public let rawValue: UInt16

    public init(rawValue: UInt16) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    public init(features: NodeFeature...) {
        var rawValue = UInt16(0)
        for feature in features {
            rawValue |= feature.rawValue
        }
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    public func hasFeature(_ feature: NodeFeature) -> Bool {
        return rawValue & feature.rawValue > 0
    }
}
```

And this is a response from server:

```
"feature": {
  "relay": true,
  "proxy": false,
  "friend": false,
  "lowPower": false
}
```

Now I need to create an instance of `NodeFeatures` with only `true` values:

```
var features = [NodeFeature]() // how to declare and prepare the list of args?

if true {
    features.append(.first)
} else if true {
    features.append(.third)
}

let wrapper = NodeFeatures(features: features) //... to pass it as a variable to the initializer.
```

But the error is following:

> Cannot convert value of type '[NodeFeature]' to expected argument type 'NodeFeatures'

Comment: try to change  init(features: Feature...) to  init(features: [Feature]).You are initializing multiple enum cases instead of single.

Comment: No, it is not the case, I need to prepare it from the other side:) The argument in initializer is from SDK...

Comment: Can you give more info?What you are doing exactly with init() part.The error is clear argument type mismatch.

Comment: `Feature` and `FeatureWrapper` is from SDK. I CANNOT change it. But I need to pass there a list of `Feature`s. The list depends on response from server:) Do you understand?

Comment: You *cannot* pass an array to a function with takes a variadic argument list. See [Passing an array to a function with variable number of args in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024376/passing-an-array-to-a-function-with-variable-number-of-args-in-swift). – If the SDK has no `init(features: [Feature])` then you are out of luck.

Comment: @MartinR, so what to pass there? How to prepare a variadic argument before I pass it?

Comment: Unless I am overlooking something, you simply *can't.*

Comment: The only way you can use it is like this `let featureWrapper = FeatureWrapper(features: .first, .second, .third)` you can't use an array

Comment: @MartinR I did update a question with EXACT class from SDK...

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: This won't help because you did not write the SDK, but an `OptionSet` would be a better suited type to represent both single features and a set of features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass an array to a function taking a variadic argument, 
or dynamically "build" a variadic argument list, compare e.g.
[Passing an array to a function with variable number of args in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024376/passing-an-array-to-a-function-with-variable-number-of-args-in-swift).

But fortunately, the type has another initializer

```
public init(rawValue: UInt16)
```

which you can use in different ways.

**Option 1:** Use an integer bit mask to assemble the features
instead of an array:

```
var rawFeatures = UInt16(0)
if condition {
    rawFeatures |= NodeFeature.relay.rawValue
} else if condition {
    rawFeatures |= NodeFeature.proxy.rawValue
}
let wrapper = NodeFeatures(rawValue: rawFeatures)
```

**Option 2:** Keep your array, but compute the combined raw value
to create the `NodeFeatures` value:

```
var features = [NodeFeature]()
if condition {
    features.append(.relay)
} else if condition {
    features.append(.proxy)
}

let rawFeatures = features.reduce(0, { $0 | $1.rawValue })
let wrapper = NodeFeatures(rawValue: rawFeatures)
```

**Option 3:** Define another initializer  taking an array argument
in an extension:

```
extension NodeFeatures {

    public init(features: [NodeFeature]) {
        let rawValue = features.reduce(0, { $0 | $1.rawValue })
        self.init(rawValue: rawValue)
    }
}
```

Now you can pass your array directly:

```
var features = [NodeFeature]()
if condition {
    features.append(.relay)
} else if condition {
    features.append(.proxy)
}
let wrapper = NodeFeatures(features: features)
```

Comment: Be careful to keep your init routine in sync with the SDK's init when you update the SDK.  They might change what init does.

Comment: Thank you, you are always very helpful:)