# Overloading 'class func' in swift

Tags: swift, class, func

I'm working on a little library to create an Image with the initials from someone's name. I have a class and a class func that actually works`class func imageWith(name: String?, textColor: UIColor = .white) -> UIImage?`I've never used `class func` before, I normally would have used `static` I was wondering if it's possible to overload the function with `class func imageWith(name: [String]?, textColor: UIColor = .white) -> UIImage?`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd expect that would work. Did you try it?

Comment: Looking at it again, one thing that might be annoying is that if you try to pass nil for the "name" parameter, it'll be ambiguous. Clients of your library will have to pass "nil as String?" or "nil as [String]?". Perhaps you could leave the array version non-optional? Passing an empty array is often just as good as passing nil.

Comment: Another option is to use [variadic parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html), they allow one or more values to be passed as a single argument. The drawback is that [they don't allow an existing array to be passed as the argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24024724/1305067), known as splatting.

Comment: Yes, I did try it. I forgot to mention that the Class is a subclass of NSObject. It keeps telling me `Method imageWith(name:textColor:) with objective c selector imageWithName:TextColor conflicts with previous declaration`

Comment: Ah, you must be using Swift 3. Writing an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting is due to the fact that in Swift 3, methods are implicitly available to the Objective-C runtime, and Objective-C doesn't support overloading. There are two options to work around this:

1. Upgrade to Swift 4, which removes the implicit @objc inference.

or:

2. Add @nonobjc to one or both of the func declarations.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Objective-C conversion issue.

Objective-C doesn't have enforced Type distinctions for classes when it calls methods, so you can't have methods with the same name.

Where Swift sees

`class func imageWith(name: String?, textColor: UIColor = .white) -> UIImage?`

`class func imageWith(name: [String]?, textColor: UIColor = .white) -> UIImage?`

Objective-C sees

`+(id)imageWithName: (id) name andTextColor: (id) textColor`

`+(id)imageWithName: (id) name andTextColor: (id) textColor`

**Solution:**

All you actually need to do to fix this is change your naming, .e.g.

`class func imageWith(names: [String]?, textColor: UIColor = .white) -> UIImage?`

which will result in Objective-C seeing

`+(id)imageWithNames: (id) names andTextColor: (id) textColor`