# Swift custom print() function ignores line break

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a logging function and everything worked fine until I found this.

This is how `print` function's interface defined.

```
public func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n")
```

so if I print `print("a\nb")`, it prints

```
a
b
```

however if I print the same string with the function below

```
func pLog(_ items: Any...) {
    print(items)
}
```

it prints

```
["a\nb"]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Swift doesn't "splat" varargs. Does that answer your question?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024376/passing-an-array-to-a-function-with-variable-number-of-args-in-swift

Comment: what you need is `items.forEach({print($0)})`

Comment: That's really weird right? But if I were you, I would just define pLog's items as String, and pass it on the print function. The String literal will work just fine. Meanwhile, I would take a closer look at variadic functions in Swift in order to understand this strange behavior.