# How can I be able to feed an array as variadic arguments in Swift?

Tags: swift

I got this function:

```
func test1(elemets: Int...) {
    print(elemets)
}
```

And here is the use case:

```
let array: [Int] = [0, 1, 2]

test1(elemets: array)
```

Xcode make error of:

> Cannot pass array of type '[Int]' as variadic arguments of type 'Int'

The goal is to be able pass an array to a variadic arguments.

Comment: This is called splatting, and seems not to be supported in Swift. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024376/passing-an-array-to-a-function-with-variable-number-of-args-in-swift

Comment: It seems like the best thing you can do is define two versions of your function, where the version of the function that takes in variadic arguments passes those arguments onto the `[Int]` implementation.

Comment: @Marcel: I know that way before asking, I was looking to extract variadic arguments from array.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible in Swift